# Why does the latest markup for gtag.js not contain any implementation for clients with javascript disabled

Tags: google-analytics

I may overlook something completely obvious, but when I look at the markup needed to enable Google Analytics on a website:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=[tracking-id]"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '[tracking-id]');
</script>
```

it does not contain any markup in the case the client has disabled javascript. Although I would expect it to be implemented as a `<noscript>` container just before the `</body>` tag, that is not mentioned anywhere on the Tracking Code page in GA. Is it handled by the reference to https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js or do I need to add some additional markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<noscript>` tag is part of the GTM container code which is comprised of two tags, the `<script>` and `<noscript>` tag.. not GA tracking code snippet.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

As per your provided code example, the Global site tag (gtag.js the current version of GA tracking code snippet)  It is specifically for Google only products without having to go the whole GTM route

> The global site tag (gtag.js) is a JavaScript tagging framework and
>   API that allows you to send event data to Google Ads, Campaign
>   Manager, Display & Video 360, Search Ads 360, and Google Analytics.
>   Instead of having to manage multiple tags for different products, you
>   can use gtag.js and more easily benefit from the latest measurement
>   features and integrations as they become available.

https://developers.google.com/gtagjs